# Display Date in a Spark DataGrid

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I have a Datagrid that gets its data from an ArrayCollection of model "beans". The ArrayCollection **Outcomes** is a list of **Outcome**

```
  <s:DataGrid  dataProvider="{outcomes}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="outcome" headerText="Outcome" width="120"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="dateRequired" headerText="Date Req" width="130"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
  </s:DataGrid>
```

**Outcome.as**

```
[Bindable]
public class ASPersonalOutcomeSummary  {

    public var _outcome:String;
    public var _dateRequired:Number;
}
```

The problem is that **dateRequired** is represented as a Number, this design decision was made so it makes it easier to pass between the AS client and Java backend.

I really want to display this number as a Date String (eg. 1 Feb 2011 or something like that) but as it is a number, it simply displays as the timestamp in the datagrid... eg.

**Outcomes  | Date Required**

---

blahhhhhh | 12389712987

blahhhhh2 | 13242342349

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `labelFunction` which is something like the following:

```
private function dateLabelFunction(item: ASPersonalOutcomeSummary, column:GridColumn):String
{
    var timeStamp:Number = item. _dateRequired;
    var date:Date = new Date(timeStamp);
    return new DateFormatter().format(date);
}
```

And then:

```
<s:DataGrid  dataProvider="{outcomes}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="outcome" headerText="Outcome" width="120"/>
            <s:GridColumn labelFunction="dateLabelFunction" headerText="Date Req" width="130"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
  </s:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do new Date(_dataRequired) in a labelFunction and then format it with a dateformatter.

Cheers